# Jenkins console: Windows fatal exception: access violation

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When I use Jenkins pipeline to call my python script, the jenkins pipeline console reports an error "Windows fatal exception: access violation". But when I connect to node and run it using cmd, it runs normally.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4DX3.png)

How to position what is the problem? How to deal with it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Jenkins is this?
Please check if any part of the python code is waiting for approval.

```
https://JENKINS_URL/manage/scriptApproval/
```

Comment: I got 404 in the uri path u give me . My jenkins version is 2.235.4.

Comment: Please check in the Jenkins configuration where the option I am talking about is located. Maybe in your version, the URL will be different.
Link to documentation:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/